# Find all the solutions $(a,b)$ $\in \Bbb Z^+$ of $(a+b^2)(a^2+b)=(a+b)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all the solutions $\in \Bbb Z^+$ of this equation

$$(a+b^2)(a^2+b)=(a+b)^3$$

**Advice:** I saw a post of the same problem but it was $(a-b)^3$, i tried applying the same logic but it didn't work.

I discover that $(n,0)$ and $(0,n)$ works with $n \in \Bbb Z^+$ but i want the non-zero solutions too.

Any hints?

Comment: Expand: $$a^3 + ab + a^2b^2 + b^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3.$$  For $a, b \neq 0$, we obtain $$1+ab = 3(a+b).$$  We see that, without loss of generality, $a \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $b \equiv 2 \pmod{3}.$  Also, eventually, $ab +1 > 3(a+b).$  Does this help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have already said, after expanding and simplifying we get:

$$ab -3a - 3b + 1 = 0$$

we can play a bit with this equality to get

$$(a-3)(b-3) = 8$$

There are eight ways the integer $8$ can be factored into pairs of divisors:

$$(8,1) \quad (4,2) \quad (2,4) \quad (1,8) \quad (-1,-8) \quad (-2,-4) \quad (-4,-2) \quad (-8,-1)$$

Since we require $a,b > 0$ we can discard the last four of them. This gives the solutions

$$a = 11,\ b = 4\qquad a = 7,\ b = 5\qquad a = 5,\ b = 7\qquad a = 4,\ b = 11.$$

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick

Answer (score 0):

Expand both sides of the equation and simplify:
$$a^3 + ab + a^2b^2 + b^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3$$
Bring everything to one side of the equation:
$$3a^2b + 3ab^2 - a^2b^2 -ab = 0$$
$$ab(3a + 3b - ab - 1) = 0$$
Assuming $a$ and $b$ are both nonzero, the problem therefore reduces to finding integer solutions to
$$3a + 3b = 1 + ab$$
Another way to think about this is that we need
$$b = \frac{3a-1}{a-3}$$
to be an integer.  So the problem reduces to finding the values of $a$ for which $3a-1$ is a multiple of $a-3$.  Can you take it from here?